Why does setting sysctl -w get overwritten back shortly?
Ubuntu 22.04
I'm new to Linux and try to configure IPv6 network. So I set
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2

The problem is it gets immediately overwritten back to the value 0. Why is that happening? Is there a way to fix that?

What distribution (and version) are you using?

@larsks Ubuntu 22.04

For reference, this has also been cross-posted on Super User in Why is eth0.accept_ra sysctl value always overwritten even after specifying in sysctl.conf?, which currently has one answer.
